# How to detect If panel in opening or closing of SlidingUpPanel in flutter

Tags: flutter, sliding

I am Using Sliding up Panel using this Package https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel ,
I want if Panel of the SlidingPanel is Opening then a value of a variable should be increment ,If Panel is closing then Vakue of variable should be decrement. below is What I have tried .Any help would be apprectiated thanks

```
  return SlidingUpPanel(
  color: Color(0xFFE44663),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),topRight:Radius.circular(10.0) ),
  onPanelSlide: (slidingPosition){
    setState(() {
      if(slidingPosition>=0.0 && slidingPosition<1.0){
        amounts++;
      }
      else{
        if(slidingPosition>0.0){
          if(amounts>=1){
            amounts--;
          }
          else{
            amounts=amounts;
          }
        }


      }

    });
```

Comment: there is two event onPanelOpened and onPanelClosed try to use it

Comment: @Merym onPanelOpened and OnPanelClosed means that the Panel is fully opened/Closed But I was to used  if Panel is opening then value should increase and if panel is closing then value should decrement.

Answer (score 0):

as in the link of the package under the Properties headline you can see  onPanelOpened, onPanelClosed properties. You can define functions to these properties. onPanelOpened define a function decrease the value, onPanelClosed define a function increase the value.

Comment: onPanelOpened and OnPanelClosed means that the Panel is fully opened/Closed But I was to used  if Panel is opening then value should increase and if panel is closing then value should decrement.

Comment: check the onPanelSlide property I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I am Using That (onPanelSlide) as you can see in Question Code section But It increment the value if Panel is  Opening but Doesn't decrement if Panel is closing

Comment: the onPanelSlide can take 0.0-1.0 and your if statement is slidingPosition>=0.0 && slidingPosition<1.0 so the the program never can reach the else statement

Comment: So What could be the solution ?

Comment: When the panel is closed the value of slidingPosition is 0 if it is open it increase automatically if you start to close it decrease so if you just return the value of slidePosition you get the value you want or you can just write amount = slidingPosition

Comment: Amount and slidingPosition are different from each other .